# Start Service When unlockScreen

Tags: android, service

How i can Start Service when unlock Screen ? maybe something like AlarmAanger !

```
context.startService(new Intent(context, Widget.class));
```

Answer (score 6):

For detecting screen on and screen off register a broadcast reciver like:

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <receiver android:name="receiverScreen">
        <intent-filter> 
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF" />
<action android:name="android.Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT" />
        </intent-filter> 
    </receiver>
```

In Activity or Service:

```
 try {
              IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);

              filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT);

              BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new receiverScreen();

              registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
         } catch (Exception e) {

         }
```

receiver code where System inform you if Screen on/off happen:

```
public class receiverScreen extends BroadcastReceiver {

     @Override
     public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

         if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)){

         }
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)){

         }
if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)){

         }
     }

    }
```